# Wordpress - How to get next 3 posts

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post 'works', and I use a plugin where a client can re-order it.

I am able to get the next post by the menu_order, but I am having so much trouble getting the next three.

For example,

0 1 2 3 4 5

I also need it to loop if it is towards the end, so if I am on post 4, I need to get 5, 0, 1.

Would anyone have any idea?

I am new to PHP, and I tried to find a way messy way to do it, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
$counter = 0;
$theID = $post->ID;

for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 

    if ($nextID !== 0) {

        $id = get_post_field('menu_order', $nextID, true);
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,       
            'menu_order'       => $id,
            'post_type'        => 'work',
            'post_status'      => 'publish'
        );
        $posts_array[] = get_posts( $args );        
    } else {

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,       
            'menu_order'       => $counter,
            'post_type'        => 'work',
            'post_status'      => 'publish'
        );
        $posts_array[] = get_posts( $args ); 
        $counter++;
    }
}

echo json_encode($posts_array);
```

Comment: Can you give us a code of what have you done so far?

Comment: Yeah, its real bad though.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues there:
 1. $nextID is used before initialization (or is not copied)
 2. get_post_field() uses post's id as param. See this link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field

I would get post, increment $counter and than, if it exceeds number of posts ($postCount), set it to 0 so, if $counter == 5 and $totalCount == 6, like in your example, it will get 5 and go to 0.

```
global $post;

$theID = $post->ID;
$counter = get_post_field('menu_order', $theID);
$postsCount = wp_count_posts('work');
$posts_array = [];

for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
    if($counter+1 >= $postCounts)
        $counter = 0;

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,       
        'menu_order'       => $counter,
        'post_type'        => 'work',
        'post_status'      => 'publish'
    );
    array_push($posts_array,get_posts( $args )); 

    $counter++;
}

echo json_encode($posts_array);
```

I haven't tested, but I hope it helps.